# FirebaseInstanceId.zzju(java.lang.String)' is inaccessible to class

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have this error in my app:

> 03-16 17:18:44.050 7026-7026/com.momentstel.vivawehdat A/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
>                                                                         java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
>                                                                             at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1696)
>                                                                             at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1671)
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4999)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4594)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4534)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzud;
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.crash.internal.config.flag.Flags.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.crash.internal.config.flag.Flags.initialize(Unknown Source)
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                             at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1696) 
>                                                                             at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1671) 
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4999) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4594) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4534) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.internal.zzud" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.momentstel.vivawehdat-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.momentstel.vivawehdat-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.momentstel.vivawehdat-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.momentstel.vivawehdat-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.momentstel.vivawehdat-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.momentstel.vivawehdat-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.momentstel.vivawehdat-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.momentstel.vivawehdat-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.momentstel.vivawehdat-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.momentstel.vivawehdat-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.momentstel.vivawehdat-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.momentstel.vivawehdat-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                                             at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                                                                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.crash.internal.config.flag.Flags.(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.crash.internal.config.flag.Flags.initialize(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.getInstance(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                             at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1696) 
>                                                                             at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1671) 
>                                                                             at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4999) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4594) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4534) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>                                                                           Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzud
>                                                                             at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                                             at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>                                                                             at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>                                                                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>                                                                                   ... 26 more
>                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
>   03-16 17:18:45.185 7026-7026/com.momentstel.vivawehdat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                            Process: com.momentstel.vivawehdat, PID: 7026
>                                                                            java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zzju(java.lang.String)' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging' (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging' appears in /data/app/com.momentstel.vivawehdat-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes4.dex)
>                                                                                at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                at com.momentstel.vivawehdat.SplaceScreeen.onCreate(SplaceScreeen.java:40)
>                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

----- Gradle Code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.momentstel.vivawehdat'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.2.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.armcha:LuseenBottomNavigation:1.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.0"
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.2.0'
    compile 'ayar.oktay.library:advancedtextview:0.4.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---- IN Splacescreen

```
 getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");
    String msg = "Thank about your Support";

    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

Comment: Use version 10.2.0 of all Firebase and Google Play Services libraries.  Mixing 10.2.0, 10.0.1, 9.2.1, 9.2.0 is not good.

Comment: Change  all your firebase library versions into 10.2.0, the problem is solved!

Comment: qbix and Ram ...  thnkx it's Solved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you have different versions of the Firebase / Google Play services dependencies. Use the latest version (currently, 10.2.0) in the following lines of your Gradle file:

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.0"
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
```

Comment: thanx @webo88  it's Done